# "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression" Error When Adding Data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, mismatch

Understandably, this is a popular error.  However, looking through the others didn't yield much useful information for me.

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
' variable listing and usage
DIM conx ' connection object to the server
DIM comd ' instance of a command object
DIM bookingsql ' string variable to hold the SQL commands
DIM itemsAdded ' numeric var to hold num records added to table (1 or 0)
DIM dbpath  ' path to the database file

set conx=server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")

conx.Provider="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
dbpath = Server.Mappath("database/thrus.mdb")
conx.Mode = 3 ' adModeReadWrite
conx.Open dbpath ' open the database

set comd=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
comd.ActiveConnection=conx

bookingsql="INSERT INTO booking (boo_UserID, boo_PerID, boo_SeaID) VALUES('" &_
session("usr_ID") & "','" & _
request("performanceid") & "','" & _
request("firstSeat")& "')" 

comd.CommandText=bookingsql 
comd.Execute itemsAdded

conx.close
set conx=nothing
set comd=nothing
%>
```

Code is also [here](https://gist.github.com/f7392d3cc946a0c91b3e).

I receive the error:

```
Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80040e07'

Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

/STUDENT/s0191958/PART2/bookprocess.asp, line 33
```

Now line 33 is simply

```
comd.Execute itemsAdded
```

So I believe it might be related to the items added command, but not actually the command. If you need any more information please let me know how I can help you- to help me :D

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the type of data added to at least one column does not match the data type that is acceptable for the column.

The SQL INSERT statement is submitting the data values as string data, should this data be a set of three numbers?  If yes, then try changing to the following, which removes the single-quotes from the values:

```
bookingsql="INSERT INTO booking (boo_UserID, boo_PerID, boo_SeaID) VALUES(" &_
session("usr_ID") & "," & _
request("performanceid") & "," & _
request("firstSeat")& ")"
```

Comment: Hi bobs thanks for your response, I see what you mean, however changing it to exactly that yeilded another error;

Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

/STUDENT/s0191958/PART2/bookprocess.asp, line 35

Thinking about it, all the data are single digit numbers, but could extend upto double digits.

Comment: Ive also noticed that session is a reserved word so this may be breaking it, so ive declared the variable I want there at the top, but is this

"user_ID" & "','" & _

the correct way to add it? Simply double quotes?